# filling missing levels in R

Tags: r, na, r-factor

I have a large dataframe of this form:

```
var1<-c("a","b")
var1<-c(rep(var1,2),rep(var1,2))
var2<-c(rep(c(2013,2013),2),rep(c(2014,2014),2))
df<-data.frame(var1,var2)
df$var3<-NA
df$var3[1]<-"x"
df$var3[3]<-"y"
df$var3[5]<-"x"
df$var3[7]<-"y"

df
  var1 var2 var3
1    a 2013    x
2    b 2013 <NA>
3    a 2013    y
4    b 2013 <NA>
5    a 2014    x
6    b 2014 <NA>
7    a 2014    y
8    b 2014 <NA>
```

I want now to get rid of the missing value and replace them in way that I can get:

```
var1 var2 var3
1    a 2013    x
2    b 2013    x
3    a 2013    y
4    b 2013    y
5    a 2014    x
6    b 2014    x
7    a 2014    y
8    b 2014    y
>
```

Can someone help me with this task. My database is very large

**NOTE**: 'var2' is a character

Comment: Are you looking to replace missing values with the previous valid entry? `fill` from the `tidyr` package should do the job.

Comment: `transform(df,var3=zoo::na.locf(var3))`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this from the `zoo` package. This function carries forward the last non-NA value in the column.

```
library(zoo)
df$var3 <- na.locf(df$var3)
```